# Python + Pandas + dataframe + Csv : storing computed value at the end of a column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am fetching data from a csv file column wise. For each column values, I am predicting a data with my model. The code is:

```
prod = pd.read_csv('/home/hp/products/prod[130].csv', engine='python')

#data_belrd = prod['BelRd(D2)'].tolist()

for i in range(3,11):
    data_belrd = prod.iloc[:, i].tolist()
    print(data_belrd)
    #print('-'*80)

    model = AR(data_belrd)
    model_fit = model.fit(2)

# make prediction
    y_belrd = model_fit.predict(len(data_belrd), len(data_belrd))
    print(y_belrd)
    print('-'*80)
```

I want to store the predicted data y_belrd in the end of the corresponding column (i th column). How to do that?

**Edit:**
The csv looks like this:
[image]

If I predict a value for the BelRd(2) column, then I want to store the value in the end of the same BelRd(2) column.

**Edit 2:**
If for BelRd(d2) column the predicted value is 2, then the column should look like this with an extra 2 at the end of the column:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is a little bit unclear.

To save to a new column in the dataframe

```
df['new column'] = data
```

To save the dataframe to CSV use:

```
df['Column Name'].to_csv('csv_filename.csv')
```

To add a row to the bottom of your dataframe, use:

```
df.append({'column name': value}, ignore_index=True)
```

To insert the value into the i'th column use:

```
df.append({df.columns[i]: value}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: want to store the data in the respictive column for which I predicted a value.

Comment: you are predicting classes (say 0-9) and want to store the predicted answer in its column? So if you predicted 2 you want to store 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0?

Comment: @Debbie you need to be more clear, is that the input or output csv? What is the output you expect? To add a column could mean so many things, what exactly do you need to happen?

Comment: The first pic is the imput csv. second one is the one after storing the output. See one extra 2 is stored in the respective col.

Comment: Thanks, you need to append a row, but you will need to pass column. See update.

Comment: column name should be fetched dynamically from loop. in my code "prod.iloc[:, i]" is the ith column.

Comment: What about now?